# Uber Api - Trying to get Access token returns html response

Tags: json, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I was able to complete first two steps of authentication process.In step 3, when I try to get access token by exchanging the authorization code I'm getting an html response, which says "Request is no longer valid".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Uber </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="icon" href="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/login/images/favicon.a767a268b86a6ce7d1099bec4a9e37aa.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/login/style-login/style.ca8265c07903e433432af8462ac98f4e.css">
  <link href="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/uber-icons/3.8.1/uber-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/uber-fonts/2.0.1/superfine.css"/>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="icon-item text--center">
            <a href="https://www.uber.com/">
                <i class="icon icon_uber
                        push--top push-small--bottom
">
                </i>
            </a>
        </div>
  <p class="login-error-title text--center">Error</p>
  <p class="login-error text--center push--top">
      Your request is no longer valid
  </p>
    </div>

<script src="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/login/scripts/analytics.30328e3569a665795cf94cbbf63985a8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Analytics.init({
        services: {
            tealium: {
                account: 'uber',
                profile: 'main',
                env: 'prod',
                geo: ''
            }
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I was able to get access token earlier in JSON response. Then I did a small code refactoring. After refactoring i'm not getting JSON response.

I tried disconnecting the application from my uber profile and retried. But still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Node? Here's a [working example](https://github.com/agraebe/Take-Me-Home-Now) using Node+Express.. There's also a vanilla JS web app included that simply takes the access_token provided after the authorization for further requests.